# FileZilla FTP Server error "425 Can't open data connection" after changing port 21 to 30

Tags: windows, ftp, connection

I am using windows server + Xampp 1.8.3 and install FileZilla FTP Server => All configurations are ok!
But when I change default FTP's port (21) to another port (30), it alerts:

```
STATUS:>    [17/04/2014 8:54:08 SA] Connecting to FTP server... xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:30 (ip = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)...
STATUS:>    [17/04/2014 8:54:08 SA] Socket connected. Waiting for welcome message...
        [17/04/2014 8:54:08 SA] 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta
        220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
        220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
STATUS:>    [17/04/2014 8:54:08 SA] Connected. Authenticating...
COMMAND:>   [17/04/2014 8:54:08 SA] USER admin
        [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] 331 Password required for admin
COMMAND:>   [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] PASS *****
        [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] 230 Logged on
STATUS:>    [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] Login successful.
COMMAND:>   [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] SYST
        [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
STATUS:>    [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] Host type detected: Unix.
COMMAND:>   [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] PWD
        [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] 257 "/" is current directory.
STATUS:>    [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] Home directory: /
STATUS:>    [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] This site supports features.
STATUS:>    [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] This site supports SIZE.
STATUS:>    [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] Setting up character encoding.
COMMAND:>   [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] OPTS UTF8 on
        [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] 200 UTF8 mode enabled
STATUS:>    [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] Using UTF-8.
STATUS:>    [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] This site can resume broken downloads.
COMMAND:>   [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] REST 0
        [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] 350 Rest supported. Restarting at 0
COMMAND:>   [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] PORT 192,168,1,111,207,240
        [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] 200 Port command successful
COMMAND:>   [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] LIST
        [17/04/2014 8:54:09 SA] 150 Opening data channel for directory list.
ERROR:>     [17/04/2014 8:54:40 SA] Timeout (30000 ms) occurred on accepting data connection from server.
        [17/04/2014 8:54:41 SA] 425 Can't open data connection.
        [17/04/2014 8:56:21 SA] 421 Connection timed out.
ERROR:>     [17/04/2014 8:56:21 SA] Control connection closed.
```

I opened port 20,21,30.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Port 20 is used as a source port for data connections in active mode (the on you use here) if the server listens on the default port 21. According to RFC959, 3.2 the default source port of the server for data connections is L-1, e.g. if L is 30 like in your case the source port should be 29 and no longer 20 so you have to allow connections from port 29.

Comment: Thank you Steffen Ullrich. I used port 30 and 31. It's working now!

Comment: 1) That means that if set the port 2100, do I have to open the 2099 for data channel in a non-secure connection? 
2) In a secure connection, the port 990 is already open in the Windows Firewall and in the hosting provider, but I not very sure about default port 989. 
3) How can I check if this 989 is open? I can't see the port 989 on LISTENING in the NETSTAT command. Is this a good approach?
4) I have an insecure connection with another FileZilla FTP Server instance on same server with the port 21 and for passive 50K-51K. Works fine, but for my secure FTP I always receive the 425 error. Thx

Comment: @MaximusDecimus 1) yes. 2+3) how to check for open ports is not part of the original question, but  LISTENING will not help since this not a listener socket and it will also be created only for transfer. 4) too few details, please ask a new question (not a comment) with enough details.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your comment. I will try to check the router that I don't have access yet and if needed I will post a question.

Answer (score 26):

You need to setup your passive ports in your Firewall. I wrote a tutorial not long ago: http://johandorper.com/log/filezilla-server-passive-ports

Comment: Even after setting up passive ports in my firewall, I had to change the "IPv4 specific" setting to "Use the following IP" and then set the IP of my external router.

Comment: i struggled for 2 hours with this issue and your solution of adding the TCP Port range 50100-51100 to both Filezilla Server and the Firewall worked. thank you.

Comment: This was the solution for me, the error I had "000001)[DATE] 20:23:24 PM - USER (IP)> 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"
"

Answer (score 0):

Also check your hosts file on windows for invalid entries. Had a help desk person with an old entry in their hosts file to the wrong ftp server and they were getting a 425.